# ImportError: cannot import name 'join'

Tags: python-3.6

```
from string import join
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'join'

I was not able to perform join operation as it stats that it cannot be imported. Tried few solutions but nothing worked. Thank you for help.

Comment: That function doesn't exist in Python 3.

Comment: Call join on a delimiter as follows (no import needed--it's an instance function, not a static class function): `",".join(["foo", "bar"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to pass the `join` function as an argument to other functions such as `map`, you can use `str.join` instead:

```
print(list(map(str.join, ('_', '-'), [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')])))
```

This outputs:

```
['a_b', 'c-d']
```